Error in signup controller Illegal arguments: undefined, string
I'm following a tutorial, trying to learn MERN. I've created function that send the data to database, but I can't see this data in the data base. Code bellow
export const signup = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { fullName, username, password, confirmPassword, gender } = req.body;

        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Passwords don't match" });
        }

        const user = await User.findOne({ username });

        if (user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Username already exists" });
        }
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);


        const boyProfilePic = `https://avatar.iran.liara.run/public/boy?username=${username}`;
        const girlProfilePic = `https://avatar.iran.liara.run/public/girl?username=${username}`;

        const newUser = new User({
            fullName,
            username,
            password: hashedPassword,
            gender,
            profilePic: gender === "male" ? boyProfilePic : girlProfilePic,
        });

        if (newUser) {
            
            generateTokenAndSendCookie(newUser._id, res);
            await newUser.save();

            res.status(201).json({
                _id: newUser._id,
                fullName: newUser.fullName,
                username: newUser.username,
                profilePic: newUser.profilePic,
            });
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid user data" });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in signup controller", error.message);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
}

When I try to go to the /api/auth/signup I receive this.
cannot GET /api/auth/signup
Maybe the problem is that I'm using a POST instead of GET request?
import express from "express";
import { login, logout, signup } from "../contollers/auth.controller.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/signup", signup);

router.post("/login", login);

router.post("/logout", logout);

export default router;

But even when I try to send the data, I receive this error
Error in signup controller Illegal arguments: undefined, string
Generally I don't know what to do here

GET !== POST = 100%. One more thing, how did you send data to the controller?

share the request body and the payload details; code looks fine

Try to install body-parser
npm install body-parser

After that add into your express application
express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
const router = express.Router();

